# Width and height of datepickers previous and next date hyperlink

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to set the width and height of the jquery datepickers 'previous date' and 'next date' hyperlinks from css.
The html code of the 'previous date' hyperlink is:

```
<a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" title="Prev" data-event="click" data-handler="prev">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span>
</a>
```

and in my css i would like to write something like

```
.ui-datepicker-next, .ui-datepicker-prev {
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
}
```

I'm not sure that this is possible.
My problem is that if i look to the layout of the hyperlink, I see that its dimension is 23px x 23px, but my background picture has the dimension of 16px x 16px, and there is a white space around/near my picture and is also clickable as you can see in the picture below.
[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give **`display: block`** to anchor tags classes and then it will accept the width and height values.

[DEMO With Height and width](http://jsfiddle.net/4cE5L/2/)